# Django - Saving a form form multiple model

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new in Django, and trying to create a simple blog platform out of it. It's where user can create/edit a blog post on the front end.

Here is my models.py

```
 class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    ......

 class Categories(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ......
```

And I created a form in the front end by :

```
#forms.py
class AddBlogForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog

class AddCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Categories

 #views.py
 def AddBlogPost(request):
    if request.POST:
      lf= AddBlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES,prefix="Lform")
      cf = AddCategoryForm(request.POST, prefix="Cform")
    if lf.is_valid() and cf.is_valid():
        addblog =  lf.save(commit=False)
        addblog.save()
        obj_id = addblog.id

        addcategory = cf.save(commit=False)
        addcatgory.blog_id = obj_id
        addcatgory.save()


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit', args=(obj_id,)))


else:
      blog= AddBlogForm(prefix="Lform")
      category = AddCategoryForm(prefix="Cform")
    return render_to_response("forms.html", locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

 #template 
 <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{blog.as_p}}
    {{category.as_p}}
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

This working actually, but I feel it is too redundant create and saving a form with two classes.It's there anyway to simplified this?

Comment: Have you looked at django class based views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use django forms to save data from a form to multiple models. For example:

forms.py

```
class AddBlogCategory(forms.Form):
    title= form.CharField(max_length=100)
    content= form.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...............
    ...............
```

views.py:

```
def AddBlogPost(request):
   if request.POST:
      form= AddBlogCategory(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          addblog= Blog() #import model class
          addblog.title= form.cleaned_data['title']
          addblog.content= form.cleaned_data['content']
          addblog.author= request.user
          .....
          addblog.save()
          obj_id= addblog.id

          addcat=Categories()
          addcat.blog= addblog
          ....
          addcat.save()

          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit', args=(obj_id,)))
      else:
          return render_to_response("forms.html", {form:'form'})
```

Its an untested code, but you can have an idea how to implement it.

Comment: Yes, I can get your idea. Seem reasonable. Will try it out, and accept this answer afterward.